# How to apply QED Feynman rules here?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, scattering, feynman-diagrams

I am reading Schwartz' QFT book, where in chapter 20, he discusses IR divergences. At the beginning of chapter 20.1.2, he considers the sum of the following diagrams in Feynman gauge and in the limit where the electron mass is negligible:
[image]
which apparently can be written by using QED Feynman rules like this:
$$ i\mathcal M = \frac{ie^2}{Q^2} \bar v(p_2) \gamma^\mu u(p_1) \bar u(p_3)S^{\mu\alpha}v(p_4)\epsilon^\star _\alpha (p_\gamma), \tag{20.26} $$
where $Q$ is the intermediate photon's momentum and
$$ S^{\mu\alpha} =  -ie \left[ \gamma^\alpha \frac{i}{\tilde p_3+\tilde p_\gamma}\gamma^\mu - \gamma^\mu \frac{i}{\tilde p_4+\tilde p_\gamma}\gamma^\alpha \right] \tag{20.27}$$
where $\tilde p=p_\mu\gamma^\mu$, since I cannot do a slash here.

---

However, I cannot reproduce this. My approach looks like:
$$ i\mathcal M = \bar v(p_2) (-ie\gamma_\mu) u(p_1) \frac{-i}{Q^2} \bar u(p_3) (-ie\gamma^\mu)\frac{i}{\tilde p_4-\tilde p_\gamma}(-ie\gamma^\alpha) v(p_4)\epsilon^\star _\alpha (p_\gamma) + \bar v(p_2) (-ie\gamma_\mu) u(p_1) \frac{-i}{Q^2} \bar u(p_3) (-ie\gamma^\alpha)\frac{i}{\tilde p_3+\tilde p_\gamma}(-ie\gamma^\mu) v(p_4)\epsilon^\star _\alpha (p_\gamma) $$
As you can see, for example one of the denominators is different. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The $p_4$ momentum is an outgoing antifermion, which you correctly identified since you have $v(p_4)$. Thus the momentum flow on the antiquark line is opposite to the arrow, so you have $p_4 + p_{\gamma}$, but you have to reverse the total sign of the propagator, since it is an internal antifermion propagator.

Comment: Of course, thank you! Do you want to write this as an answer so I can accept it? If not, I'll wait some time and write the answer myself.